# In and Case statements in Where

Tags: sql

Here is my code, it does not return anything and I am not sure how to handle the case in the where...

```
Select distinct u.semail email, '' blank 
FROM user u inner join
     group g
     on u.hgroup=g.hmy
where u.binactiveuser = 0 and
      u.hgroup in (case when @application = 'Test1' then (Select hmy from group where ucode like 'pay%')
                          else case when @application = 'Test2' then (Select hmy from group where ucode in ('cc','vente','leas'))
                               else case when @application = 'Voy' then (Select hmy from group where ucode not like 'pay%' and ucode not in ('cc','vente','leas'))
                                    end
                               end
                     end)
```

Comment: (1) You should tag the question with the SQL you are using.  (2) This code will not work in any database, because `group` is a reserved word.

Comment: You should also include some information on what it is you want the query to do, and perhaps some sample before/after data.

Comment: Gordon, I have truncated the table names, my table is mgroup. I am trying to get the answer on my SQL version.

Comment: jpw, I need to create an extract that will have my users email address separated by a comma. This is why my second column will be ''. I am extracting this in a csv format so opening it in notepad will let me copy the email addresses with the comma in between. This will help me create custom mailing lists tu use in gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an OR would work...

```
Select distinct u.semail email, '' blank 
FROM user u inner join
     group g
     on u.hgroup=g.hmy
where u.binactiveuser = 0 and
      (
       (@application = 'Test1' and u.hgroup in (select hmy from group where ucode like 'pay%'))
       or
       (@application = 'Test2' and u.hgroup in (Select hmy from group where ucode in ('cc','vente','leas')))
       or
       (@application = 'Voy' and u.hgroup in (Select hmy from group where ucode not like 'pay%' and ucode not in ('cc','vente','leas')))
      )
```